# jquery position() doesn't work in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I've tried a workaround to correctly position some images inside a div with a border radius.
I need to move images 1px to left and 1px to top, and I used jQuery .offset() function. It works correctly on firefox, opera and IE, but doesn't work on chorme.

The code is the following

```
$(window).load(function(){
    // adjust social icons
    $("div.nuvola.social img").each(function(){
        var tmpOffset = $(this).offset();
        tmpOffset.left -= 1;
        tmpOffset.top -= 1;
        $(this).offset(tmpOffset);  
    });
});
```

I uploaded an example in this test page (social icons on the top right)
[LINK](http://nieto.hostingplaza.org/cory/index.php)

Comment: Why are you doing this with JavaScript instead of CSS?

Comment: on chrome version 20.0.1096.1 (Official Build 131343) dev-m, I can see the code works Ok

Comment: The images in your example link are sliding up and to the left for me (Chrome 18). What version of Chrome are you using? @Sparky672 is right, though, it seems like you're going about this the hard way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe...

http://nieto.hostingplaza.org/cory/css/style.css (line:76-82)

```
div.nuvola.social img {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 70px;
    left: -1px;
    top: -1px;
}
```

Don't forget to add "px";